# List owner and size of specific txt or log files belonging to each user (csv format), in batch

Tags: batch-file

I need to generate a csv file containing the owner and size of a particular file (text or log file) for each user. To get this I need to go to C:\Users\ and for each user go to a path (the same for all users) and find a specific file that can have either a .log or .txt extension. Then I need the file's owner and the file size written to a csv file.

I have the below batch script, but it shows the path, file name, and size under a directory. Can anyone please help me meet the above requirements?

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /r %%a in (*) do for /f "tokens=5" %%b in ('dir /q "%%~fxa" ^| findstr "%%~nxa"') do (
    echo "%%~dpa","%%~nxa","%%~za","%%b"
)) > test.csv
```

Comment: This would be much simpler in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Please know that questions that only provide cut & paste code with a list of requirements are often not answered, but this may show you some of the basics. It writes username,filename,filesize for each log or txt file to output.txt in the Users dir. You can modify it to list username and file size only. Note: File size is given in **bytes**

The code you posted ran for all files in the dir it started from and all subdirs. It could probably be modified to return only the data you want for only your specified files in the paths you're interested in, but I wasn't able to do it--and it would be indecipherable to someone who doesn't know batch. This is longer, but you will be able to follow. It's explained below.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

        Set "file=FileNameWithoutExtension"
        Set "filepath=PathFromUsers\ToFileDir"

    :: Go to Users dir and delete old output file
        cd %SystemDrive%\Users\
        Del output.txt >nul 2>nul

    ::  Loop through the Users directory
        For /d %%G in ("*") do (
            Set "filename="
            If exist %SystemDrive%\Users\%%G\%filepath%\%file%.txt set filename=%file%.txt
            If exist %SystemDrive%\Users\%%G\%filepath%\%file%.log set filename=%file%.log
                :: !marks are required to expand variables set inside a loop
                If not "!filename!"=="" (
                    pushd %SystemDrive%\Users\%%G\%filepath%
                    For %%A in (!filename!) do echo %%G,!filename!,%%~zA >>%SystemDrive%\Users\output.txt
                    popd
                )
        )
    echo Done!
    exit
```

You need to set the variable at the top: The file name (without the txt or log extension) and the "some random path" that runs from Users directory to the directory with the file you want to check.

The For /d loops through each Users directory (%%G) looking for the txt or log file in the filepath you set and if a file is found (If Exist), the file name is stored in var "filename". Next, if a file was found--filename var is **not** empty--(1) the pushd goes to the directory the file is in, (2) the For %%A extracts the file size (%%~zA), (3) using echo, the username (corresponds to user directory--%%G), filename, and file size are written to output.txt, then (4) popd goes back to Users dir for the next iteration.